# Как найти максимальный элемент среди значений по ключам в словаре в цикле?

Tags: python, словари

У меня есть словарь

```
dict = {'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10': {' 0': -78.857, ' 2': -80.738, ' 1': -79.679}}
```

Я хочу найти максимальный элемент среди -78.857, -80.738 и -79.679

Я попробовал достать их

```
listsum = []

for key in dict.keys():
  for key in (dictt.keys()).keys():
    listsum.append(((dict.keys()).keys()).values())
print(listsum)
```

Чтобы далее найти в списке наибольший с помощью max()

Но Pycharm выдал мне ошибку

```
for key in (dict.keys()).keys():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  как это можно сделать

Comment: Чтобы не грузить своими названиями переменных переименовал в dict, здесь забыл. Исправил, спасибо.

Comment: `dict` - плохое название для переменной, оно перекрывает встроенный тип питона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значения надо брать, а не ключи:

```py
dict_ = {'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10': {' 0': -78.857, ' 2': -80.738, ' 1': -79.679}}
print(max(max(d.values()) for d in dict_.values()))
```